# Visualisation of Stack Overflow tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I have made various interactive visualizations based on Stack Overflow data. You can check the whole collection of visualizations at [GraphOverflow](http://graphoverflow.com). The outcome is pretty interesting.

Some of them are...

[Relation between tags in Stack Overflow](http://graphoverflow.com)
[image: Main graph]

[How are tags growing?](http://graphoverflow.com/graphs/stackoverflow-tag-growth-rate-montly.html)

[image: Tag growth]

[Which was the trending tag last year?](http://graphoverflow.com/graphs/stackoverflow-tag-trending-yearly.html)

[image: Trending tags]

Etc.

Play with it, enjoy :)

Comment: **COOL!** Maybe even show it off on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/news)?

Comment: *sigh*, this existed quite safely on MSE for a while before being migrated here by a member of the community team. If you really think it's off-topic then please at least comment to explain _why_.

Comment: @Ben, While I do think this is an awesome visualization, I don't see how this is asking for a community discussion.